# How to build this simple generative model?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

I'm watching a lecture and it shows (schematically) a model with 2D input (sampled from Gaussian) followed by 12 conv layers, and output an RGB image.

That's all about it, no training at all! he relied on initializations only. He did it just to illustrate the concept of NN power to produce complex distributions.

How can I dot that in Keras?

Comment: PS: The idea is that NN can map from simple distributions that we have power over to something crazy in high dimensions (like an image). I know it is easy but I can't write a code for it though.

Comment: Is it true that I need DEconvolutional layers?